# what is the use of recursive relationship and a relationship to an undefined model in Django?

Tags: python, database, django, relational-database

Text below is from Django docs which provide

> To create a recursive
>   relationship – an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself – use models.ForeignKey(’self’).
>   If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model,
>   rather than the model object itself.

can someone give me an example of the usage of these capabilities in Django?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it to create links to other objects of this Model.

For example if you have many members in a website and each has an inviter (also of Member type) you can do the following:

```
class Member(Model):
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        related_name="invited_set"
    )
```

If you want the inviter, you do:

```
Member.objects.get(id__exact=5).inviter
```

If you want all members that this member has invited you use:

```
Member.objects.get(id__exact=5).invited_set
```

Answer (score 1):

For models not yet defined:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title_image = models.ForeignKey('Image')

class Image(models.Model):
    part_of = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
```

since these classes refer to each other, at least one of them needs to refer to a class not yet defined.